# JavaFX Controller not detecting objects (Intelij IDE)

Tags: java, javafx

I've been trying to work on some CSS and also using JavaFX for the first time. Saw a few basic tutorials and tried starting my calculator. Got stuck inside the controller. Let me first show u the code i used:

Main

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainFX.fxml"));
        Scene sceneMain = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(sceneMain);       //scene setup

        String css = this.getClass().getResource("calcFX.css").toExternalForm();
        sceneMain.getStylesheets().add(css);    //adding css



        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("CalcFX");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package app;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Controller {

    private Text text = new Text("");
    @FXML
    private Label display;
    display.setText(text);
}
```

FXML file

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="350.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label id="display" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" text="" />

      <GridPane hgap="6.0" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" vgap="6.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="45.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button id="b0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Press0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="45.0" stylesheets="@calcFX.css" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Button id="b1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Press1" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="45.0" stylesheets="@calcFX.css" text="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button id="b2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Press2" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="45.0" stylesheets="@calcFX.css" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button id="b3" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Press3" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="45.0" stylesheets="@calcFX.css" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The issue is that when i try to reference the "display" object which is a label, it treats it like its undefined and cant detect it. Same with the Text text element, the IDE doesnt seem to understand that its a Text object. Anyone can explain this, i bet its a silly mistake on my side, I've had over 2 years break from programming so i might be a little rusty.

EDIT: Thank you for reminding me not to put random code inside of a class, completely forgot about the very basic stuff it seems. Still i found the real issue i had before, which was the code not actually detecting the Label variable and sayings its a null object. Turns out the FXML was not injecting the FXML code because in my fxml file the label had [id="display"] while it should have been [fxid="display"].

Issue resolved, post closed :)

Answer (score -2):

Welcome back to programming!

I think you should define a string instead and set your label text as that string also, all statements in java need to be inside a method. and not just in the class. So you could have your code as

```
private String string= "";
@FXML
private Label display;

public void initializeText(){
   display.setText(string);
}
```

You could then call the initializeText() method to display the text.

Using the Text class as a parameter in the setText() function is not defined in the Documentation from Oracle.

You could go through the documentation for more information

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html

Comment: I changed it into string and still the same problem.

controller 13:20
java: <identifier> expected

this is the piece of code where the last line is the 13th:

    private String text = "";
    @FXML
    private Label display;
    display.setText(text);

Comment: https://ibb.co/Wk69ZBb this is the screen. setText i in red so its not even identifying it as a proper object for some reason

Comment: You can't just have statements in the class body.  It is syntactically wrong and won't compile.  You need to [put statements in methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) unless you are defining and [initializing a field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) as part of the same operation (which you aren't).